# Bring a row for each specific column that is not empty, with the column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I've this table with the following data:

| ID | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | Data4 | Data5 | Data6 | RandomInformation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 |  | Test2 |  | Test3 |  | Information1 |
| 2 |  | Test5 |  | Test6 |  | Test7 | Information2 |
| 3 | Test8 | Test9 |  |  | Test10 | Test11 | Information3 |

The resultant table i want should be as below:

| ID | Data | RandomInformation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Data1 | Information1 |
| 1 | Data3 | Information1 |
| 1 | Data5 | Information1 |
| 2 | Data2 | Information2 |
| 2 | Data4 | Information2 |
| 2 | Data6 | Information2 |
| 3 | Data1 | Information3 |
| 3 | Data2 | Information3 |
| 3 | Data5 | Information3 |
| 3 | Data6 | Information3 |

Can someone please help me out with this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY` in concert with `VALUES` to `UNPIVOT` your data

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.Data
      ,A.RandomInformation
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ('Data1',Data1)
                     ,('Data2',Data2)
                     ,('Data3',Data3)
                     ,('Data4',Data4)
                     ,('Data5',Data5)
                     ,('Data6',Data6)
             ) B(Data,Value)
 Where B.Value is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to mention column names , here is a more dynamic way:

```
SELECT t.id, t.RandomInformation, b.[Key] AS data 
FROM tablename t 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * 
             FROM OPENJSON((SELECT t.* FROM tablename FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER))) b 
WHERE b.[Key] NOT IN ('ID', 'RandomInformation')
```

inspired by John Cappelletti

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can also use UNPIVOT to do this. ie:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
  (
    ID                INT
  , Data1             VARCHAR(50)
  , Data2             VARCHAR(50)
  , Data3             VARCHAR(50)
  , Data4             VARCHAR(50)
  , Data5             VARCHAR(50)
  , Data6             VARCHAR(50)
  , RandomInformation VARCHAR(50)
  );

INSERT INTO @myTable(ID, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5, Data6, RandomInformation)
VALUES(1, 'Test1', NULL, 'Test2', NULL, 'Test3',NULL, 'Information1')
    , (2, NULL, 'Test5', NULL, 'Test6', NULL, 'Test7', 'Information2')
    , (3, 'Test8', 'Test9', NULL, NULL, 'Test10', 'Test11', 'Information3');

SELECT d.ID, d.x, d.RandomInformation, d.Data 
FROM
(SELECT ID, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5, Data6, RandomInformation FROM @myTable) t 
UNPIVOT
(
   [Data] FOR x IN (Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5, Data6)
) AS d;
```